# else block is not working in Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have 4 pictures and one button(Play)

When i press the button a random sound(D/H/P/S) will be lounched !

when I click on the right Image (exp: if it goes H i should click on the H image)
 if i choose right and alert goes (bravo!)
else 
an alert with a failure sound will be lounched !

in my situation whenever i click it goes bravo!

please tell me what's wrong in my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div id="deviceready">

    <h2>Ecoutez et choisissez une lettre</h2>
    <img src="img/play.jpg" style="width:40px;" id = "playAudio">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th><img src="img/D.png" style="width:80px;" id="D"></th>
        <th><img src="img/H.png" style="width:80px;"id="H"></th>
        <th><img src="img/P.png" style="width:80px;"id="P"></th>
        <th><img src="img/S.png" style="width:80px;"id="S"></th>
      </tr>
    </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    var myMedia = null;
var nb;
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
         onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        myMedia = new Media("/android_asset/www/audio/1.mp3");
        document.getElementById("playAudio").addEventListener("click",                      playAudio);
             document.getElementById("D").addEventListener("click",function(){compare(1)});
             document.getElementById("H").addEventListener("click",function(){compare(2)});
             document.getElementById("P").addEventListener("click",function()  {compare(3)});
             document.getElementById("S").addEventListener("click",function(){compare(4)});

    },
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    }
};

app.initialize();

function playAudio() {
     nb = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
    var src = "/android_asset/www/audio/"+nb+".mp3";
    myMedia.stop();
    myMedia.src = src ;
    myMedia.play();
}
function compare(x){

    if(nb=x)
        {
            alert("Bravo!");
            return;
        }
    else
        var srcc="/android_asset/www/audio/failure.mp3";
    myMedia.src=srcc;
    myMedia.play();
}
```

Comment: Generally, we're not here to help you debug your code. What else have you tried? What measures have you taken to test? What errors are you explicitly getting?

Comment: Easy to spot: `if(nb=x)` asigns x to nb. Use `==` instead to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's always true

```
if(nb=x)
```

change to

```
if(nb==x)
```